# Local notification handling when application is closed

Tags: ios, event-handling, notifications, localnotification

I have a question related to handling notifications but in case of application is closed. In my iOS application I schedule the local notifications, and I successfully handle them when application is either in foreground or background. But when application is closed and I get local notification I can't handle it. I mean after pressing "show" button I have to move the user to a specific window. But I don't know where to put the part of the code which deals with handling.
Any idea???
Thanks in advance.

Armen

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show code block so that we can rectify it.

Answer (score 0):

Check `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` in your app delegate, you should receive dictionary from your notification as launching options, as far as I know.

[Try this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html)

Answer (score 0):

I could post some code hear but i think the better way is no copy/paste work. So here is the link after they show single notification, they explain how to handle notifications. [tutorial about handling notifications](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-local-notification-tutorial/)